# Apache 2.4.7 mod_proxy_wstunnel tunneling too much (HTTP as well as WS)

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, websocket

I'm running Apache 2.4.7 as a reverse proxy on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  This Apache server acts as the entrypoint to a lot of different backend applications, which are accessed via different mod_proxy configurations in `<Location>` blocks

I need to provide reverse proxy access to an application that uses WebSockets.  The application is a Java Spring application that serves HTML and other static files over HTTP, and then uses a WebSocket for dynamic data after the page has loaded.

I've got the application running behind `Nginx` using the following config:

```
location /newapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://newapp.example.com:8080/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Unfortunately, due to needing an Apache authentication module that isn't available on Nginx, I can't use this in production.

What I want to do, in pseudo-Apache-config is:

```
<Location /newapp/>
    if not WebSockets:
        ProxyPass http://newapp.example.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse /
    else
        ProxyPass ws://newapp.example.com:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

The Apache `mod_proxy_wstunnel` module makes me think that this should be possible.  The WebSocket is accessed on the URL `/api/socket/...`, so I've tried separating the two types of `ProxyPass` using separate `<Location>` blocks:

```
<Location /newapp/>
    ProxyPass http://newapp.example.com:8080/ disablereuse=on
    ProxyPassReverse /

    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain newapp.example.com apps.example.com
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath http://newapp.example.com:8080/ /newapp/
</Location>

<Location /newapp/api/socket/>
    ProxyPass ws://newapp.example.com:8080/api/socket/
    ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

This works initially - the browser requests http://apps.example.com/newapp/, the page loads over HTTP, the static assets are loaded, the JavaScript code connects to the websocket, everything is awesome.

However, when a new request is made over HTTP - say, for `GET /newapp/static/someimage.png`, something goes wrong.  This request doesn't match against the WebSocket Location, so I would expect it to proxy `GET /static/someimage.png` through to `http://newapp.example.com:8080/`.

Instead, the application server receives a request for `GET /newapp/static/someimage.png` and returns a 404, as this isn't a URL that it's aware of.  This breaks the application, as HTTP requests that should work fail instead.

Notes:

- This doesn't just occur for images - `GET /newapp/api/ajax/someapicall` also gets proxied through incorrectly.
- This doesn't always happen.  While testing things to complete this question I managed to get the app to completely work.  It might have been time based - I left the app running without interacting with it for a few minutes before making any new HTTP requests.  When I did make new HTTP requests, they went through correctly.
- Disabling the `<Location /newapp/api/socket/>` section causes two things to happen - the WebSocket fails to connect, and the HTTP requests continue to work.
- I discovered this issue after refreshing the page via the browser's Refresh button.  Instead of the page loading again, I saw the app's 404 screen.

What I think is happening:

I think `mod_proxy_wstunnel`, once activated by the first request to match `/newapp/api/socket/`, is taking over for all further inbound requests from the client, whether they match the `Location` or not.  I tested this by adding a `RequestHeader set Test "some_identifying_value"` directive to each `Location` - the HTTP requests for static files & for `/api/socket/info` had the `Test` header on them, but the incorrectly-proxied HTTP requests did not have a `Test`
header on them, which suggests that they are being passed straight through without being processed by the Apache directives.

Ultimately, my question is this: Is it possible to configure any version of Apache (I'm happy to upgrade!) to reverse-proxy WebSocket-based applications in such a way that HTTP requests are also reverse-proxied correctly after the WebSocket has connected?  If so, how is this configured?

Comment: Firstly: thank you very much for reading this!  I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Secondly: AAARGH this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

anders' answer got me 95% of the way there.

The basic scenario:

- We have a server on `newapp.example.com`
- Port 8080 is running both HTTP and WebSockets
- The URL that responds to WebSockets requests is `/api/socket/`
- We're reverse-proxying this application as `http://apps.example.com/newapp/`

This is how to configure WebSockets and HTTP reverse-proxying for the above scenario in a `<Location>` block:

```
<Location /newapp/>
    ProxyPass http://newapp.example.com:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
    RewriteRule /api/(.*) ws://newapp.example.com:8080/api/$1 [P]
</Location>
```

The final rewrite rule is crucial - without it, we'll pass the request `/newapp/api/socket` through to the WebSocket server - which it will reject.

The regex is parsing out everything after `api` - there might be a better way to capture that block, but this worked.  We then have to remember to re-add `/api/` to the final redirect URL.

Most importantly, HTTP requests continue to work after the WebSocket connection is established!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using apache 2.4 as a proxy in front of my spring boot app, this app serves some rest api calls, websockets (sockjs) and some static pages. I had some problems getting the websocket to work, the secret there was to add [the rewrite rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002744/how-to-set-up-an-apache-proxy-for-meteor-sockjs-and-websocket) you see below, now it works for me, my apache virtual host config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/my.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/my.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/intermediate.crt
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyRequests Off
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
  RewriteRule .* ws://localhost:6868%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
  ServerName my.dnsname.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This was *so close*!  Thank you so much!  I had to make a few changes to make it work in a <Location> block, though